# Fetch element with common id among two array but id must be unique for each sets of arrays in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to fetch elements having a common id from 2 sets of arrays but that id must be unique to each array, the array can contain multiple-element with the same id, in that case, it should not fetch the item. Only if the id is common between two arrays and is unique to each array.

```
var fetchElement = ArrayA.Where(x=>ArrayB.Any(y=>y.Id == x.Id)).ToArray();
```

Above code will return me the elements with common ID.
eg:

```
Array 1 
[
{id = 123, name ="abc"},{id=456, name="def"},{id=123, name ="ghi"}
]
Array 2 
[
{id =123, name ="abc"},{id=456, name ="def"}
]
```

Array 1 and Array 2 both have id 123 and 456 but I only want the element with id 456 as it is unique for both of the arrays.

Comment: I think you are looking for [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-intersect-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

```
var Array1 = new[] { (id: 123, name: "abc"), (id: 456, name: "def"), (id: 123, name: "ghi") };
var Array2 = new[] { (id: 123, name: "abc"), (id: 456, name: "def") };

var query = from a1 in Array1.Where(x => Array1.Count(y => y.id == x.id) == 1)     
            join a2 in Array2.Where(x => Array2.Count(y => y.id == x.id) == 1)
            on a1.id equals a2.id
            select (a1, a2);

foreach (var x in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.a1} {x.a2}");
}
```

For sure there are more efficient ways, but maybe it's sufficient for you.
[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TrI0tq)